# Is it necessary to use application.html.erb for the page layout?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

Is it okay not to use application.html.erb at all? instead just use the controller(s) actual html ? What is the use of application.html.erb?

- views

  - book
    -index.html.erb
  - aboutme
    -about.html.erb
  - layouts
    -application.html.erb    -mailer.html.erb    -mailer.text.erb

Comment: You can specify no layout at all for a view or another layout for a view, you could even specify a specific layout view for each view if you wanted. So, yes it is totally o.k. to not use the default application.html.erb for your layout on any or all views, however I am not sure what you mean when you mention the controllers actual html, your controller should not have any html in it.

Comment: @RockwellRice i actually meant the view html, that was generated like from my post, views > book > index.html.erb , i'm still not familiar with the terms sorry.

Answer (score 1):

The anser to your question is yes.  The application.html.erb layout is applied by default, here are some other options.

no layout applied

```
render :layout => false
```

This would go inside the view's method, for example

```
def index
  @books = Book.all
  render :layout => false
end
```

This would remove any layout file from the index view for Books 
`yoursitename.com/books`

You can also specify a different layout file that you have.

```
def index
  @books = Book.all
  render :layout => "books_layout"
end
```

Probably worth your time as well http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

Answer (score 0):

It is ok not to use the application.html.erb file, you could specify what ever layout file you want and you're not limited to one.

You could do this for an action or the controller.

The purpose of the application.html.erb file is to setup the layout for you're view files.

Just to clarify, your views that you have for example under books: index.html.erb are being showed because of the application.html.erb file. If you look in that file you will se the yield function and that's what making your content inside index.html.erb to be visible.